# how to dynamically Change number of products per row - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin in my custom theme. By default woocommerce show 4 product per row, but I want to show it according to total product in a category.
For Example 
If have 3 product in a category than display 3 product in one column.
If have 6 or 9 product display 3 product per column. or
If have 8 total product than display 4 product per column.
if have 12 product or more than display 6 product per column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will ensure the hmtl is correct. However you will still have fix the css, but I don't do alot of theming, so I can't really help you there.

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'my_loop_shop_columns');
function my_loop_shop_columns() {
    global $wp_query;

    // calculate the amount of products visible on the current page
    $posts_on_page = min($wp_query->found_posts, $wp_query->get('posts_per_page'));

    if($posts_on_page >= 12) return 6;
    if($posts_on_page % 4 == 0) return 4;
    if($posts_on_page % 3 == 0) return 3;
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank You so much for your help. this code is working good but how can I add css class in single product li to according our conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: Hi
I may need to add a custom classname to the product tag:
This should allow my css to specify different block widths depending on the number of columns, eg:
.custom-3-cols .products .product {width:33%}
.custom-4-cols .products .product {width:25%}
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can always use jquery to recount your products. This is one way of doing this and its clean and simple solution.

```
First in functions remove the smallscreen css from woocommerce like so if needed (i prefer to remove it since i dont use it):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'woo_dequeue_styles' );
function woo_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Then creat a js file if you dont have and enqueue it in your theme and add the following code.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).ready(productsCount);
$(window).on('resize',productsCount);

function productsCount(){
    // This is example of 4 per row so you may need to tweek those
    // First remove the first and last classes added by woocommerce
    $('ul.products li').removeClass('first last');

    //For resolutions equal or above 992px wide 4 per row
    if($(window).width() >= 992) {
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('first');
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(4n)').addClass('last');
    }
    //For resolutions between 991px and 768px wide 3 per row
    if($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() <= 991) {
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(3n+1)').addClass('first');
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('last');
    }   
    // For resolutions between 580px and 767px wide 2 per row - it just look 
    // better in my designs so you may want to tweek this
    if($(window).width() >= 580 && $(window).width() <= 767) {
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('first');
        $('ul.products li:nth-child(2n)').addClass('last');
    }       
    // Here we remove any woocommerce class since we dont need them.  
    if($(window).width() <= 580) {
        $('ul.products li').removeClass('first last');
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```